# value_counts() return more than two columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the dataframe presented bellow:

```
import pandas as pd

data=pd.DataFrame({"Year": [1982, 1983, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1982],
                   "Status": ["Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No"]})
```

I need to aggregate values by `'Year'` and `'Status'` columns and count values in `'Status'` column.

My code below does not give the result I expected.

```
evo=data.groupby(['Year','Status'] )['Status'].value_counts()

Year  Status  Status
1982  No      No        1
      Yes     Yes       2
1983  No      No        1
      Yes     Yes       1
1984  No      No        1
Name: Status, dtype: int64
```

**Desired result presented bellow:**

|  | Year | Status_yes | Count_yes | Status_no | Count_no |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1982 | yes | 2 | no | 1 |
| 1 | 1983 | yes | 1 | no | 1 |
| 2 | 1984 | yes | 0 | no | 1 |

I wish I can get evo dataframe and use for the plot figures later. How could I do that? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you will find this format more convenient for further use in building graphs and charts.

```
import pandas as pd

# set data
data = {"Year": [1982, 1983, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1982], "Status":["Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No"]}

# create pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# create pivot table
df1 = pd.pivot_table(df, index='Year', columns='Status', aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)

df1
```

Returns

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but by running your code, I can not get your result as showed.  it is shows : Year Status
0 1982 Yes
1 1983 No
2 1982 Yes
3 1983 Yes
4 1984 No
5 1982 No

Comment: @julie, there was a typo in the last row of the code. `df` suppose to be `df1`. Corrected

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `size()` to get the counts

```
evo = df.groupby(['Year','Statut']).size().reset_index(name='counts')
evo
```

#### Output

[image]

Comment: it is not correct.